# Tkinter: How to freely place LabelFrames into frames with classes?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to put some frames into a main frame with Tkinter.
I used `LabelFrame` in each class and I want to place them with a specific position (I don't want to use some `sticky=` option).

I tried to configure each `LabelFrame` with `ipadx` / `ipady` but I can't make a frame larger only from the bottom (it becomes larger from the top and the bottom...). The `grid` method doesn't seem to be the solution...

I think I'm missing something while trying to code this in OOP.

Here is an example of what I'm trying to do:

```
import tkinter as tk


class Root(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        Class1(self)


class Class1(tk.LabelFrame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        tk.LabelFrame.__init__(self, master)
        self.grid(row=1, column=0, ipadx=400, ipady=250)
        tk.Label(self, text = "CLASS 1").pack()
        Class2()


class Class2(tk.LabelFrame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        tk.LabelFrame.__init__(self)
        self.grid(row=1, column=1, ipadx=200, ipady=250)
        tk.Label(self, text = "CLASS 2").pack()
        Class3()


class Class3(tk.LabelFrame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        tk.LabelFrame.__init__(self, master)
        self.grid(row=2, column=0, ipadx = 400, ipady = 275)
        tk.Label(self, text = "CLASS 3").pack()


root = Root()
root.geometry('1400x800')
root.mainloop()
```

`

Comment: I don't know if I understand problem but if you want to set it freely then use `place()` instead of `grid()`

Comment: you could send parent to all classes - you could use master for this - `Class2(master)`, `Class3(master)`

Comment: I run code but I don't undestand what is the problem. I don't understand what you try to get. Maybe draw image with expected layout - and add to question (not to comment).

Comment: In fact, I'm not trying to do anything particular. I just want to put some frames into a main frame and be able to place and size them freely, like I would do it for a label with `place()` for example. But since I'm using classes, I can't do it as directly as i want. Also, what will send parent to all classes exactly change ? Thx !

Comment: as I said use `Class2(master), Class3(master)` instead of `Class2(), Class3()`. But I don't know what is your problem because I see all frames in main window. And classes has nothing to do with position - grid will always place it at the top because empty rows/columns have no size. You would have to insert empty label in some row to move element in row below. Eventually you need `padx, pady` to add external margin.

Comment: Ok now I understand what you meant... I thought it was more complicated than that so didn't go to the right direction. With @Derek routine I see it now, thx !

Answer (score 1):

Try this, it enables you to position a `labelframe` and to resize it with `button-1` and `button-3`

It uses place manager.

```
import tkinter as tk

x, y, w, h = 20, 0, 400, 250

class Root(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.config( cursor = 'crosshair' )
        self.class1 = Class1(self)

class Class1(tk.LabelFrame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        tk.LabelFrame.__init__( self, master )
        self.place( x = x, y = y, width = 400, height = 250 )
        #master.label = tk.Label( self, text = "CLASS 1" )
        #aster.label.place( x = 10, y = 10, width = 380, height = 220 )

root = Root( )
root.geometry( '1400x800' )

def mover( ev ):
    global x, y, w, h
    if ev.num == 1:
        x, y = ev.x, ev.y
        root.class1.place( x = x, y = y, width = w, height = h )
    elif ev.num == 3:
        w, h = abs( ev.x -x ), abs( ev.y - y )
        root.class1.place( x = x, y = y, width = w,  height = h )
    root.class1[ 'text' ] = f'x = {x} | y = {y} | w = {w} | h = {h}'

root.event_add( '<<POSIT>>', *( '<Motion>', '<Button-1>', '<Button-3>' ) )
root.bind( '<<POSIT>>', mover )

root.mainloop( )
```

Comment: Thanks ! But unfortunately my problem doesn't come from labels (I put labels just to identify the frames). It comes from the dispatching of my frames into the main frame. I would like to get rid about the grid/pack things and place them wherever I want.

Comment: I think this routine may help  @ThOpaque.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! It works fine when using `place` and this routine was really helpful !

Comment: Happy coding @ThOpaque.